# How to remove repetitive code that differ in using properties/fields for displaying themselves as strings?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, c#-4.0

I have two extension methods that are very similar. I'd like to remove the code duplicates with [«the hole in the middle»](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/04/04/functional-c-the-hole-in-the-middle-pattern/) pattern or the like, but can't really get it to work.

The code looks like so:

```
public static String GetPublicPropertiesAsString( this Object @this )
{
    return @this.GetType().GetProperties()
        .Select( propertyInfo =>
                        {
                            var propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue( obj: @this,
                                                                    invokeAttr: BindingFlags.Public,
                                                                    binder: null,
                                                                    index: null,
                                                                    culture: null );

                            var propertyValueAsString = propertyValue != null ? propertyValue.ToString().RemoveAll( "00:00:00" ) : "[null]";

                            return "{0}: {1}".FormatWith( propertyInfo.Name, propertyValueAsString );
                        } ).JoinAsString( Environment.NewLine );
}

public static String GetFieldsAsString( this Object @this )
{
    return @this.GetType().GetFields()
        .Select( fieldInfo =>
                        {
                            var fieldValue = fieldInfo.GetValue( @this );

                            var fieldValueAsString = fieldValue != null ? fieldValue.ToString().RemoveAll( "00:00:00" ) : "[null]";

                            return "{0}: {1}".FormatWith( fieldInfo.Name, fieldValueAsString );
                        } ).JoinAsString( Environment.NewLine );
}
```

Could the repetitive code above be refactored away?

Note: `JoinAsString`, `RemoveAll`, and `FormatWith` are my own extension methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can. By using generics and the fact that both PropertyInfo and FieldInfo derives from MemberInfo.

Something like this:

```
static string GetAsString<T>
    (object @this, Func<T, object> getter) where T : MemberInfo
{
  return @this.GetType().GetMembers(/* binding flags */).OfType<T>().Select(
    x => 
    {
      var value = getter(x);
      var valueAsString = value != null ? value.ToString().
           RemoveAll( "00:00:00" ) : "[null]";
      return "{0}: {1}".FormatWith( x.Name, valueAsString );
    }).JoinAsString();
}
```

Now the hook up:

```
public static String GetPublicPropertiesAsString( this Object @this )
{
  return GetAsString<PropertyInfo>(@this, x => x.GetValue(@this, null));
}

public static String GetPublicFieldsAsString( this Object @this )
{
  return GetAsString<FieldInfo>(@this, x => x.GetValue(@this));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor that middle code out to a single method that accepts `MemberInfo[]`, and does a switch on the member type. Untested, but:

```
    private static string GetMembersAsString(object @this, MemberInfo[] members)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < members.Length; i++)
        {
            var member = members[i];
            if (i != 0) sb.AppendLine();
            object value;
            switch(member.MemberType) {
                case MemberTypes.Field:
                    value = ((FieldInfo)member).GetValue(@this);
                    break;
                case MemberTypes.Property:
                    value = ((PropertyInfo)member).GetValue(@this, null);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException(member.MemberType.ToString());
            }
            string s = value == null ? "[null]" : value.ToString().RemoveAll("00:00:00");
            sb.Append(member.Name).Append(" = ").Append(s);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    public static String GetPublicPropertiesAsString(this Object @this)
    {
        return GetMembersAsString(@this, @this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance));
    }

    public static String GetFieldsAsString(this Object @this)
    {
        return GetMembersAsString(@this, @this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance));
    }
```

Comment: It might remove the code dupes, but it also refactors the original declarative code into imperative, which IMHO reduces readability.

Comment: @Martin well, we could have retained FP by passing in the `GetValue` terms for each, but to be honest (and particularly on private implementation methods) I'm not sure that getting stressed over FP vs others is a debate worth having. As long as it works, etc....